# python AttributeError

Tags: python, function, attributeerror

I have three python files

`one.py`, `two.py`, `three.py`

`one.py`

from `one.py` I call

```
import two as two  
    two.three()
```

in `two.py` I have

```
def two():
    "catch the error here then import and call three()"
    import three as three
```

in `three.py` I have

```
def three():
    print "three called"
```

so naturally I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'three'

My question is:

Is there a way to have `two.py` capture the error then import `three.py` and then call `three()`?

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*edit****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**_V
I can call it like this:

```
two().three()

def two():
    import three as three
    return three
```

but I would like to call it like so:

```
two.three()
```

So essentially it would auto exec def two():

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve (on a broader level)?

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that you mean to say `from two import two` and `from three import three` instead?

Comment: I am trying to create a global object that I can call. 
so the import will happen then the functions will be available after the import.

Comment: Why not just import them right away? You probably can add new functions to a module after it's been created but this seems more confusing than useful. (Posing a question this abstract is a good way to cause the XY problem.)

Comment: The module `two` does not contain `three` when you import it; so you _should_ get an error. But your error suggests that `one` sees `two` as a **function**, not as a module. This is impossible with the code you give: you probably have `from two import two`, as @neir suggests?

Comment: I plan to have many different files: in each file I may have several classes functions and/or constants(vars). I want to be-able to call one module that acts as a global mapper, it should query the caller and decide what action should be taken.

Comment: On a side note: I'd pursue this approach with caution, as it hides what your calling modules really depend on, and renaming a file or refactoring a method resolved in this way would mean having to change every single caller - it's unlikely be supported by IDE tooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. I confess that I was inspired by your question to try to figure this out, so I don't completely understand it myself. The magic happens in two.py where the attempt to access and then call the `three` method of `two` is handled by the `__getattr__` method of the `method_router` class. It uses `__import__` to import the indicated module by name (a string), and then imitates the `from blah import blah` by calling `getattr()` again on the imported module.

one.py

```
from two import two
two.three()
```

two.py

```
class method_router(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        mod = __import__(name)
        return getattr(mod, name)

two = method_router()
```

three.py

```
def three():
    print("three called")
```

Comment: I wanted to do it like this:  two.three() but wont work it will work like this two().three()
    def two():    import three as three    return three

Answer (score 0):

When you are invoking a module there is no way the invoked module can check by itself whether it has a function and if not follow an alternative path. You could wrap two.three() around try except clause catching an attribute error.

```
try:
   two.three()
except AttributeError:
   three.three()
```